# How to change Cellcolor in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to Copy the Colorinformation from an other Cell into a new Cell.

Ok that works well but my new Cell is everytime black instat of e.g. yellow

here is my code of this:

```
private void cellChange(Cell cell, XSSFCell newCell, XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle) {
try
{

  XSSFCell tt = (XSSFCell) cell;
  XSSFColor color = tt.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
  newCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
  newCellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  newCellStyle.setFont(newFont);
  newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

}
// .. catch omitted
```

tt was in this case a test  if it fix when i use a XSSFCell instat of Cell from the ss usermodel.

Can you help me in this case?

Example

```
public class ChangeCell{

public ChangeCell(){
  try
  {
    File file = new File("C:\\ENTWICKLUNG\\testfolder\\out\\test.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFWorkbook newWb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFCell oldCell = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0);

    XSSFSheet newSheet = newWb.createSheet("Test");
    XSSFRow newRow = newSheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(0);
    newCell.setCellValue("TestForCell");

    XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = newWb.createCellStyle();

    cellChange(oldCell, newCell, newCellStyle);
    newWb.write(new FileOutputstream("newTest.xlsx");
    newWb.close();     
  }
  //.. catch omitted
}

private void cellChange(Cell cell, XSSFCell newCell, XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle)
{
  try
  {

    XSSFCell tt = (XSSFCell) cell;
    XSSFColor color = tt.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
    newCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
    newCellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

  }
  //.. catch omitted
}  }
```

The color in the test.xlsx  in the Cell A1 should be Red or Yellow.

Comment: tt was the XSSFCell i fixed it in my post.

i put it in that way in the cell because of, my newStyle didnt have the setfillforgroundcolor(Color color) and only with a short. when im going on and trasform my Coler in a short with .indexed(), i get the same reason that my cell is black. 

i think the correct color is stting in cell.getCellStyle.getFillBackgroundColorColor();

Comment: that works like befor, i will update the code on my main post, but i have the same problem like before i didnt get the right color.

Comment: also with Forgroundcolor i get a Black instat of a yellow cellcolor

Comment: same like the whole time its black not yellow, i had it in my code like  you said but had obsolate code and copyed it with it in the start post

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Else no help is possible in my opinion.

Comment: i add an example

Answer (score 2):

Not ckear what you are doing wrong.

The following code works for me using `apache poi` current stable version `3.17`. Note `FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND` instead of `CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND`. But there is no reason why it should not works using older versions which provides `CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND`.

test.xlsx:

[image]

code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class ChangeCell{

 public ChangeCell() throws Exception {

    File file = new File("test.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFWorkbook newWb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFCell oldCell = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0);

    XSSFSheet newSheet = newWb.createSheet("Test");
    XSSFRow newRow = newSheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(0);
    newCell.setCellValue("TestForCell");

    XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = newWb.createCellStyle();

    cellChange(oldCell, newCell, newCellStyle);
    newWb.write(new FileOutputStream("newTest.xlsx"));
    newWb.close();     

 }

 private void cellChange(Cell cell, XSSFCell newCell, XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle) throws Exception {

    XSSFCell tt = (XSSFCell) cell;
    XSSFColor color = tt.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
    newCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
    newCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChangeCell changeCell = new ChangeCell();
 }  
}
```

testNew.xlsx:

[image]

Comment: I´m really Confused now, i changed it what you said but in my case it dosent work.

I´m iterating over 10 cells and change there the color, im overwrtiting it every time, but it dosent work

im using poi-3.8.jar

Comment: Works for me using `apache poi`version `3.17`  and your `test.xlsx`. But [apache poi Version 3.8-FINAL](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.8-FINAL) is 5 years old now and many changes was made and bugs was fixed until current version 3.17. So it is ancient in terms of software development. Using such ancient software is like using copper chisels as ancient Egyptians have done.

Comment: test it again and again only black, followed lib im using now:
commons-collections4-4.1
curvesapi-1.04
dom4j-1.6
poi-3.17
poi-ooxml-3.17
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17
xmlbeans-2.6.0

Comment: I have found the problem, in my main methode the oldCellStyleInformation gets Corrupted. I had fixed it now. ty for help

Comment: @Cris Night: You haven't provided a `main` method in your code example. So how shall this question now be helpful for others? It is useless now as it is. A forum is **not** a self-service store for free code.